# Problem install visual paradigm classcastexception

Tags: visual-paradigm

I'm trying to install Visual Paradigm 15.0. After the install4j wizard is prepared, an error occurs:

> java.lang.ClassCastException; com.install4j.runtime.beans.action.misc.LoadResponseFileAction cannot cst to com.install4j.api.screens.Screen

Any suggestions how I could go about this?

Comment: I tried to make your question a bit easier to read. Please review my changes. And look into [mcve], and see if you could describe more clearly which steps actually lead to this problem.

Comment: What is the exact file name of the installer you using?
What is its file size (in byte)?

Comment: the file name is Visual_Paradigm_CE_15_1_20180807_Win64 and the size is 518 Mo.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get around this problem is using the InstallFree package. With the InstallFree package you can simply download, unzip and run it. The InstallFree package can be downloaded form the Download page of Visual Paradigm website, and the v15.0 is available under the **Download Old Version** section.

Comment: i have tried to use the installfree package but when i click to the exe it shows nothing. the folder is called : Visual_Paradigm_15_1_20180807_Win64_InstallFree

Comment: In this case I recommend you drop an email to Visual Paradigm's support team for help.